# Clarification for Color Implementation in Fractal Flame IFS

Tags: colors, transparency, logarithm, fractals, gamma

I came across this [PDF file](https://web.archive.org/web/20130704150718/http://flam3.com/flame.pdf), and I wanted to write my own Fractal Flame generator. I'm trying to understand what the sections on Log-Density Display, Coloring, and Gamma Factor are trying to say though. As of now I think it says to use this algorithm to determine the [0-255] value of each color channel for an opaque image:

```
var log_log = log(pixel_counter)/log(max_counter),
    alpha_gamma_factor = color_channel*log_log^(1/gamma),
    color_gamma_factor = log_log*color_channel^(1/gamma),
    vibrant_color = vibrancy*alpha_gamma_factor+(1-vibrancy)*color_gamma_factor,
    corrected_color_channel = floor(256*vibrant_color);
```

Where `vibrancy` and `color_channel` are [0, 1), the counters are integers, and `gamma` is a value between `sqrt(5)` and `sqrt(16)` (or ~2.2 and 4).

Please let me know if this is right, and if not, how I should change the algorithm. I'd also like to make a variation of the algorithm that supports semi-transparency, as the output will be PNG files. What would be the highest quality algorithm for the alpha channel for [0, 255] (transparent to opaque respectively) in that case?